# Python BeautifulSoup extract text from SPAN and A tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want extract text from SPAN and A tags and put in list like this schema:

['Farina', '500 g']['Uova', '1']['Sale','100 g']

scraping with BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import string

markup = """
<dd class="ingredient">
    <a href="#">Farina</a>
    <span>500 g</span>
</dd>
<dd class="ingredient">
    <a href="#">Uova</a>
    <span>1</span>
</dd>
<dd class="ingredient">
    <a href="#">Sale</a>
    <span>100 g</span>
</dd>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'html.parser')

allIngredients = []
for tag in soup.find_all(attrs={'class' : 'ingredient'}):
    #[tag.text for tag in tags]
    link = tag.a.get('href')
    nameIngredient = tag.a.string

    contents = tag.span.text
    quantityIngredient = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", contents).strip()
    allIngredients.append([nameIngredient, quantityIngredient])

print(allIngredients)
```

sometimes SPAN can be empty or not exist

Comment: share the page `link` here than I help you

Comment: <dd class="ingredient">
    <a href="#">Sale</a>
    <span>100 g</span>
</dd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `lxml` (instead of `bs4`)

```py
from lxml import html

markup = """
<dd class="ingredient">
    <a href="#">Farina</a>
    <span>500 g</span>
</dd>
<dd class="ingredient">
    <a href="#">Uova</a>
    <span>1</span>
</dd>
<dd class="ingredient">
    <a href="#">Sale</a>
    <span>100 g</span>
</dd>
<dd class="ingredient">
    <a href="#">Vino</a>
</dd>
"""

root = html.fromstring(markup)
result = []
for node in root.xpath(".//dd"):
    a = node.xpath(".//a")
    span = node.xpath(".//span")
    result.append((
        a[0].text_content() if a else None, 
        span[0].text_content() if span else None
    ))


print(result)
# [('Farina', '500 g'), ('Uova', '1'), ('Sale', '100 g'), ('Vino', None)]
```

Comment: i will try i must change all script i'm not programmer

Comment: Why with SPAN tag i cannot to use .text or .string?

Comment: I think the method you're looking might be `.text_content`

Comment: lxml show [('Avocado', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(2)\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t500...

Comment: result = []
for node in root.xpath('.//dd[@class="gz-ingredient"]'):
 a = node.xpath('normalize-space(.//a/text()[normalize-space()])')
 span = node.xpath('normalize-space(.//span/text()[normalize-space()])')
 result.append((
  #a[0].text_content() if a else None,
  #span[0].text_content() if span else None
  #if a else None,
  #if span else None
  a, span
 ))